# Rails Console is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

I am getting the following error when trying to issue the rails c command. I have followed advice on other questions and uninstalled minitest v5 and reinstalled to v4 but no fix. Does anyone know a way to get around it? Thanks.

```
 MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:328:in `autorun': uninitialized class variable @@installed_at_exit in Test::Unit::Runner (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:640:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:312:in `initialize_console'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you share some more information about your setup? Do you use RVM? How did you install Rails? Are you following some tutorial? The more information you can offer, the better.

Comment: Hey @xlembouras. Sure.. I did install ruby and rails via RVM. I done this through a youtube video, this one I think (http://youtu.be/hiPQynmnsiI) ... I have been following this tutorial  on how to create a blog and got to the 2nd lesson where the rails c command didnt work. These are the tutorials: (http://youtu.be/-GQmC-8k09c) (http://youtu.be/UQ8_VOGj5H8) ... RVM -v is rvm 1.26.7 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]... Ruby -v = ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [i686-linux]ubuntu .. Rails -v: Rails 3.2.16.

Comment: @ezuk Ran out of characters there. initially 'rails c'was getting blocked by this: active_support/test_case.rb:12:in `<module:ActiveSupport>':uninitialized constant Test (NameError) .. I then edited the test_case.rb with require test/unit and now the error has moved on to this minitest one. Do you need any more info? thanks

Comment: @ezuk ....................... I'm not sure if this is tagging your name or not.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/users/592229/ezuk)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

You have to add the test-unit gem to your gemfile: `gem 'test-unit'`
and `bundle install` (if it's rails3).